# Swift Dictionary with Array of Strings remove Value

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

So, I have a Dictionary that contains an Array of Strings like this:

```
var dict = ["Section1": ["dev1", "dev2"], "Section2": ["dev3", "dev4"]]
```

And now I have to be able to remove a value from the array.
Example: 
I want to remove "dev4" no matter if its in "Section1" or "Section2".

How would I be doing this?

Comment: You surely tried *something,* didn't you? Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a "please write the code for me" question!

Comment: sorry for that. I tried several attemts like writing the values to array, removing that array from the dict, filtering it and reataching it. but none of it came out like i need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key in dict.keys {
    dict[key] = dict[key]!.filter({ $0 != "dev4"})
}
```

Comment: `dict.keys.forEach { dict[$0] = dict[$0]!.filter{$0 != "dev4"} }`

Comment: you can force unwrap the values considering that you are iterating through the dictionary keys

Comment: Great, thank you very much!! I searched in that direction but didn't get the syntax right

Answer (score 3):

With **Swift4** there is an option to apply a map to the values of a dictionary:

```
var dict = ["Section1": ["dev1", "dev2"], "Section2": ["dev3", "dev4"]]
dict = dict.mapValues{ $0.filter{ $0 != "dev4" } }
```

which gives the result:

```
dict // -> ["Section1": ["dev1", "dev2"], "Section2": ["dev3"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code:

```
func removeValue(value: String, fromDict dict: [String: [String]]) -> [String: [String]] {
    var out = [String: [String]]()
    for entry in dict {
        out[entry.key] = entry.value.filter({
            $0 != value
        })
    }
    return out
}

var dict = ["Section1": ["dev1", "dev2"], "Section2": ["dev3", "dev4"]]
let new = removeValue(value: "dev4", fromDict: dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mini version:

```
dict.forEach({ (k, v) in dict[k] = v.filter({ $0 != "dev4" }) })
print(dict) // ["Section1": ["dev1", "dev2"], "Section2": ["dev3"]]
```